# How to open YouTube embedded video in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have embedded YouTube video. I tried to open it in a new tab but failed. How can I open an embedded YouTube video in new tab? I tried different ways, but I can't find the solution.

My code is here:

```html
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpx8xCC7ETM" target="_blank">
  <iframe width="100" height="60" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpx8xCC7ETM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture">
   </iframe>
</a>
```

Comment: Post the different ways you have tried.

Comment: Please follow https://codepen.io/hue94/pen/XMGmbe

Comment: You shouldn't dictate a users actions in this aspect. What if the user does not want to go to the youtube link? What if the user wants to play, say a youtube music video while reading more on the current page? The youtube embed inherently includes these links. There's no point in embedding a video and not using it? Maybe you just need a thumbnail or something similar

Comment: I followed your codepen.io/hue94/pen/XMGmbe and i found the answer what i want thanks a lot Hasanuzzaman Rana

Answer (score 1):

Just show a thumbnail of the video and when the user clicks on it open youtube on a new tab.

In this example, wpx8xCC7ETM is your video id. replace it with another if you want.

```html
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpx8xCC7ETM" target="_BLANK"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/wpx8xCC7ETM/0.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to open youtube video in new tab

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbjHvDmwEJ0" target="_blank" title="Click me">
   <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/wpx8xCC7ETM/1.jpg" />
</a>
```

Or want to check live demo? [click here](https://codepen.io/skgacharya/pen/rPQyeB)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```html
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpx8xCC7ETM" target="_blank">
  <iframe width="100" height="60" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpx8xCC7ETM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture">
   </iframe>
</a>
```

Comment: i want it in different tab not in same tab it means i want to display thumbnail in website and somebody clicks then redirected to youtube

Comment: try to click at the edge of youTube

Comment: ya i know but i want it whole i mean whole embedded area clicks then redirect in youtube

Answer (score 0):

you can use YouTube data API to get link of thumbnails and display that as an image inside anchor tag.
Google APIs explorer URL for the same: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=wpx8xCC7ETM&_h=1&
you may learn more how to use it in documentation, and call it as required using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic way to extract a youtube thump from a videoId.

Have a look at the code below

```js
// base url for thump image
var baseUrl = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/{ID}/0.jpg"
$("a").each(function(){
var videoId = $(this).attr("videoId") // video id content 
var url = baseUrl.replace("{ID}", videoId); // generate a thump url for the videoId
$(this).append("<img src='"+url+"' />") // insert an image to the selected link
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a videoId= "UQzEVP_YRT8" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQzEVP_YRT8">

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for to redirect to a youtube video in a new tab try the following:

`` window.open(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${url}`, "_blank") ``